# How add code to display both Character avatar and text in 2 different scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a scene game with a Character Avatar and its name (The interface has a text field to add in it its name) and then when I clicked the DONE button, I want to run a new scene to display both Character Avatar and the name added into text field, for it, Could anybody help me to make the code to do it? Thanks in advance Alejandro Castan Ps. Sorry for my little English and hope you can understand me

```
void FinishWindowContents (int windowID) {

GUILayout.BeginHorizontal(horizontalLayoutStyle);

GUILayout.BeginVertical(verticalLayoutStyle);
GUILayout.Label ("Name", bottomBarLabelStyle);
characterName = GUILayout.TextField(characterName);
GUILayout.EndVertical();

GUILayout.BeginVertical(verticalLayoutStyle);

if (characterName.Length == 0) {
    GUI.enabled = false;
}

if (GUILayout.Button("Done", bottomBarButtonStyle)) {

    // Save the character, fade out the camera and load up the game scene
    GameObject avatarGO;

    if (selectedGender == "Man") {
        avatarGO = maleAvatarSpawn;
    } else {
        avatarGO = femaleAvatarSpawn;
    }

    var avatar = avatarGO.GetComponent<UMAAvatarBase>();
    if( avatar != null )
    {
        string finalPath = savePath + "/" + characterName + ".txt";
        if (finalPath.Length != 0)
        {
            PersistentNameHolder.characterName = characterName;

            var asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<UMATextRecipe>();
            asset.Save(avatar.umaData.umaRecipe, avatar.context);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(finalPath, asset.recipeString);
            ScriptableObject.Destroy(asset);

            // If the camera has a fader, make it fade out and load the game scene, otherwise just load the scene ourselves
            if (orbitCamera.GetComponent<CameraFader>() != null) {
                orbitCamera.GetComponent<CameraFader>().fadeOutAndLoadScene(gameSceneName);
            } else {
                Application.LoadLevel(gameSceneName);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (characterName.Length == 0) {
    GUI.enabled = true;
}

GUILayout.EndVertical();
GUILayout.EndVertical();
```

}

Note-I added some code(this code is more complex that I asked above) you can see it. This code is from Unity plugin and what I would need to add only the text added in the text field into the new scene when I do click in the Done button.

Answer (score 0):

[PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is a way to save data between scenes.

It doesn't need some extra code and is great for what you are doing because it allows you to write/read in any moment of your game.

Hope you'll find useful.

Comment: Hi Salvador. Sorry for the delay and thanks for your help ! Regards